# TList<T>.count return value mocking with Delphi Mocks

Tags: delphi, delphi-mocks

In my unit test there is a need to setup a mocked `TList<T>`. How can I setup a return value for a mocked `TList<T>.count` property read?

When I use `count` after `When` the compiler error message is:

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(40): E2014 Statement expected, but expression of type 'Integer' found
```

When I use `getCount` after `When` the compiler error message is:

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(40): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'getCount'
```

The `count` property reads directly the `fCount` attribute. Is there any solution?

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  end;

procedure TXXXTestCase.testYYY;
var
  mL : TMock<TList<TMyClass>>;
begin
  mL := TMock<TList<TMyClass>>.create;
  try
    // ...
    mL.Setup.WillReturn( 1 ).When.Count;
    // ...
  finally
    mL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Unless you use low-level hooking, the only way to mock the `Count` value is to add dummy values to the list. As for `When`, it looks like Mocks can only handle property reads that use virtual getter methods (so it can hook the methods). Besides, a statement like `MyList.Count;` is not valid in Delphi anyway (same compiler error). You will have to wrap your `Count` check in another class/method that is Mocks-compatible.

Comment: Yes my idea was the same : using inherited TList with a getCount virtual method or creating a function getListCount( aL_ : TList<T> ) : integer begin aL_.count; end; method in then user class. All of them are hacking. Refactoring a code just to be able to test. But not in the right direction. :(

Comment: Mocking a list is a bad idea, just put the values you want it to contain.

Comment: @StefanGlienke yes. except the case when the container of the list is a mock as well. :)

Comment: Then you tell it to give you a list with the values in it that you want. FWIW: http://tuhrig.de/everytime-a-mock-returns-a-mock-a-fairy-dies/

Comment: @StefanGlienke You are right Stefan! I should create and call a getter method in the first mocked class, instead of accessing the attributes like a chain (4ex : attribute.attribute.list.count) and then I can mock the result of this getter method. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Inspired by Stefan Glienke comment I created a utility calss to avoid accessing a a porperty of a property of ... of a mocked object. I just pass the mock to the mock of the utility class to get the (fake) value.

A code snipet looks like my original one:

```
value = object1.property.list.count;
```

The solution for this deep inside look:

```
value = object1Utility.getListCount( object );
```

The TObjec1tUtility calls Object2Utility to its respond, but in this case I can mock Object1Utility, no need to add a mock into a mock.